# Is Unity's physics ahead of rendering or behind?

Tags: unity-game-engine

To my understanding of [this diagram](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), `Update()` is called strictly once per game cycle, while `FixedUpdate()` is called 0 to multiple times when Unity feels like to do physics. Is it true?

What I'm not sure is, are physics steps commonly behind current time, or ahead of current time? In other words, how is Unity's decision made for doing physics or not, like `while (currentTime - previousPhysicsUpdateTime >= fixedDeltaTime)` or like `while (currentTime > previousPhysicsUpdateTime)`?

Or neither of the above?

Comment: Physics and rendering are completely separated. Physics occurs on a fixed time step, independently of your frame rate. If you have really high framerate, there can be no physic update for multiple frame, if your frame rate is really low, there can be multiple. You can't really (and shouldn't) try to predict / try to bound both.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit like to opposite. Physics is done regularly on a fixed time basis. That means that `FixedUpdate` is called on a fixed time basis. It is the Update, that can vary depending on the fps of the game (60 fps, Update was called 60 times per second).

Now, we usually thing from the `Update` point of view. Meaning that if you have a high fps, maybe you can have two `Update` calls before a `FixedUpdate` happens. In the same way, if you fps drops you have less `Updates`, but still the same amount of `FixedUpdate`, so you will have several `FixedUpdated` between two `Updates`.

So for example, let's say FixedUpdate happens 50 times per seconds (that's the default in unity). It you game runs at 60 fps, It means most of the time you will have one FixedUpdate and one Update call. Occasionnaly two Updates will follow (because Update is a bit more frequent). If you reach 100 fps, it is sure that you will always have at least two `Update` calls before a `FixedUpdate`.

I suggest you look at the [FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) Doc if this is not clear enough

Comment: Thanks. Physics may indeed be regular for the virtual world, but I suspect it's not regular from humans' point of view.
According to that diagram, physics loop is inside the main loop, so it has to rely on the main loop's frequency. 
Let's say if a game's physics takes no time but its rendering is heavy burden. 
The game runs at 1.0 fps so the main loop needs 1s to finish. During rendering, physics can do nothing but wait to make up a deficiency. So physics is like: runs 50 times for 0s, waits for 1s, runs 50 times for 0s, waits for 1s... Not verified but I feel Unity works this way.